# Confused about a function returning a function in java script

Tags: javascript

```
function a(){
   function b(){
      alert("hi");
   }
   return b();
}
function c(){
   var d = a();
}

c();
```

When I execute the above, I get the alert "hi".
but if I do as below

```
function a(){
    function b(){
       alert("hi");
    }
    return b();
}
function c(){
    var d = a();
    d();
}

c();
```

I am expecting to see two alerts for assignment and function call statements in c();, but i get only one alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look inside your console. `TypeError: undefined is not a function` -  `d` is not a function

Comment: You aren't returning a function; you're calling it.

Comment: @rene A question is only off-topic if it doesn't fall within the realm of programming, or is asking for someone to provide you with an entire solution. Just because a problem is relatively easy to solve, doesn't mean that it shouldn't be asked. This is a Q and A website, after all.

Comment: @nbrooks That might be true, point is when I reviewed this question it had already two close votes for minimal understanding which is not a good reason at all, hence my custom reason for closing. I'm not sure I agree 100% with your position because I still feel that questions that can be solved if an OP uses some of the functionality build-in in the browser or IDE or debugger are off-topic. I retracted my close-vote in favour of your point-of-view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion stems from the difference between invoking/calling a function and having a reference to that function.  When you add the `()` to a function reference you are invoking that function which returns the result of executing that function (and not the function itself).

So in this line:

```
function c(){
    var d = a();
    d();
}
```

You are assigning `d` to the result of the function invocation rather than the function reference.  As the returned value is not a function itself, the call to `d()` will fail.

The same also applies in the top function where you have (this seems to be the more likely area of mistake):

```
return b();
```

The present code will execute the function and return the result, if the desired behavior was to return a reference to the function itself it should not have the `()`.

Answer (score 6):

Because method `a` is not returning anything since `a` is calling `b` in the return statement but `b` is not returning anything so `d` is undefined whcih will cause `d()` to throw an error

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mTc8x/)

```
function c() {
    var d = a();
    alert(d)
    d();
}
```

If you see the fiddle, the second alert shows undefined as the value of d

Answer (score 4):

You are calling an undefined function.

```
function a(){
    function b(){
       alert("hi");
       // no return => return undefined
    }

    // the result of b() === undefined
    return b();
}
function c(){
    // assign the result of a to variable d
    // (which is itself the result of b, which is undefined, because b has no return)
    var d = a();

    // call undefined function, this will throw an error
    d();
}

c();
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to return the function reference,  not call it:

```
return b;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, you are basically returning the result of the alert, which should be `undefined`.

```
var d <= a() <= c() <= b() <= alert('hi') // alert returns undefined
```

Calling `d` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute c() in the second example the following will occur:

- executing function a
- in a: executing function b
- in b: executing alert (no return, so undefined is returned)
- in a: returning undefined value from b
- var d now contains undefined
- executing d should throw exception: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Use some tools like chrome's js console to run and debug js.